# Fortran code produces runtime error 'operation not supported' when attempting to open a text file

Tags: fortran, runtime-error, fortran95

I am trying to run a piece of fortran code written in f95. I have compiled it using gfortran in Ubuntu.

In the code there is a command to read in a text file. When I run it, it gives me the following error:

```
    Fortran runtime error: Cannot open file 'input_parameters.txt': Operation not supported
```

This is the code up until the point that we attempt to read the text file:

```
    program LSmodel
    implicit none !this is a fortran thing that means that all variables that start with i,j,k,l,m,n are integers. 

    real :: sec,ran,gasdev                        ! random generator variables
    real :: x,y,z,u,v,w,ut,vt,wt,t,dt             ! simulation variables
    real :: wg                                    ! seed parametes
    real :: Um,sigma_u,sigma_v,sigma_w,uw         ! wind statistics variables
    real :: dvaru_dz,dvarv_dz,dvarw_dz,duw_dz     ! wind statistics variables
    real :: dissip_m,TL                           ! vector over the range of ustars
    real :: zs,zg,zmax                            ! release height & boundaries
    real :: Ainv,C0inv                            ! inverse parameters
    real :: C0,A,b,au,av,aw,dt_on_TL              ! LS model parameters
    real :: dz_max,dt_max                         ! time step limit
    real :: CT,beta                               ! Crossing Trajectories correction
    real :: C_chi,chi,TKE,T_chi,omega             ! DI parameters
    real :: a_ln,b_ln,sigma_chi,dissip_s          ! DI parameters
    real :: rhop,rho,r,g,gt,Re,AIP,Cd,nu          ! IP parameters
    real :: up,vp,wp,upt,vpt,wpt,vr,dt_ip,alpha   ! IP parameters
real :: keepseed, maxheight
    integer :: seed                              ! random generator variables, keepseed decides whether to keep the same seed or not for comparison of simulation
    integer :: pnum, traj_exit     ! simulation parameters. traj_exit counts the number of particles that have exited from the topo f the wind flow. 
    integer :: i,j,jj,n,ii                        ! counting parameters
    integer :: n_ip,IP=1                          ! IP parameters
    character(len=80) :: filename, wgchar, foldername
    real, allocatable,dimension(:) ::  z_vec,Um_vec,sigma_u_vec,sigma_v_vec,sigma_w_vec,uw_vec
    real, allocatable,dimension(:) ::  dvaru_dz_vec,dvarv_dz_vec,dvarw_dz_vec,duw_dz_vec,dissip_m_vec


    ! input
    open (23,file='input_parameters.txt') !opening a file for the input parameters....
    read (23, *) x,C0,wg,zs,zg,beta,dt_on_TL,y,sigma_chi,C_chi,r,rhop,alpha,rho,nu, keepseed, foldername
    close(23)
```

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

Comment: You should add how you compiled your program, and maybe how you ran it. Also juste in case, the file is present in the directory where the program is executed ?

Comment: Also, just for clarification `implicit none !this is a fortran thing that means that all variables that start with i,j,k,l,m,n are integers.` is wrong. Implicit none means the compiler wont implicitly infers a type from the first letter of a variable. So if a variable is not declared, an error is raised.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this error with gfortran 9.2.1. Your code compiles and runs fine for me with an input_parameters.txt of `1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 10.0 11.0 12.0 13.0 14.0 15.0 16.0 myCoolFolderName`.

Comment: The output of "ls -l input_parameters.txt" in the directory where you are trying to run it might be useful as well

Answer (score 0):

An update - I have found (I believe) the reason this code was not working, although I don't know why.

The folder was in a network drive, not on my local computer. Once I moved the folder onto my local computer, I stopped getting this error.